# EF 4.3 using local cache instead of re-fetching from database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Can someone explain to me why my EF (4.3) code first code below is resulting in the "old" password being retrieved.

```
using (var context = new CableSenseInstanceConfiguratorContext())
{
    var user = context.Installers.Where(u => u.UserName == "admin").FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(user.Password); // Outputs "oldpassword"

    // Change the details on a different context;
    using (var context2 = new CableSenseInstanceConfiguratorContext())
    {
        var installer = context2.Installers.Single(i => i.UserName == "admin");
        installer.Password = "changed"; 
        context2.SaveChanges();
    }

    var user2 = context.Installers.Where(u => u.UserName == "admin").FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(user2.Password); // Outputs "oldpassword"
}
```

The password is "oldpassword" to start. So I'm changing the password inside another context (context2), and then fetching it again into user2. I can verify that the output is "oldpassword" for both. From profiling the SQL, I can see that the password does get changed, I can also see that the code that populates user2 *IS* going to the database, but it's just not using those values.

I understand that EF has the concept of the Local context as a way of caching and tracking entities, but from what I understand, a `context.Installers.Where(..)` should force a refetch from the database, whereas a `context.Installers.Find()` should look in the local context. It seems that no matter how I query Installers, it is using the local cache.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Reinard for the solution. I was misunderstanding the docs - I read from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/28/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-3-finding-entities.aspx):

> Note that DbSet and IDbSet always create queries against the database
>   and will always involve a round trip to the database even if the
>   entities returned already exist in the context.

So I assumed that because it would go to the database, it would re-fetch my object. What actually happened is that it went to the database, fetched the object, found I already was tracking that object (because of the previous load), and so I ended up with the old object - this is actually what the docs say!

Using `context.Installers.Local.Clear()` makes no difference surprisingly, I needed `AsNoTracking().`

Comment: Are you sure you are compairing the same records? In the first context you are using .Where(...).FirstOrDefault() and in the second context you are using .Single(...). Is the generated SQL identical?

Comment: I can't reproduce the described behavior and agree whit @Maarten

Comment: Absolutely 100% certain - the only different Linq expression is with the second context that I'm using to update the record in the DB, so it doesn't matter so much that this Linq is different. The profiler verifies that the right record gets updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither `Where` or `Find` will explicitly refetch from the database. As far as I know Find will retrieve the entity from the database only if it doesn't exist in the context.

In order to explicitly force a refetch use AsNoTracking().

e.g.

```
context.Installers.AsNoTracking().Where(u => u.UserName == "admin").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Brilliant - I understand what is happening now :) I was mis-unstanding the docs, thanks for this - I'll edit my question to elaborate

Comment: Excellent, I was just looking for this very same answer since I needed to get the original full obj graph as it is in database and compare it to other modified instance